# Unity2D - Questions About DontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the game I'm currently making, I'm calculating the score and time with a script attached to my Player object. I want to create a new scene that will act as a results screen when a level is cleared.

If the script is attached to my Player, that means my Player should be present in the results screen as well, right? I'm unsure of how DontDestroyOnLoad actually works, since I've never used it before. Would it just be easier to move the camera to another part of the level instead of making an entirely new scene?

Here is the relevant code for my problem:

```
public GUIText scoreText;
public GUIText timerText;
private int score;
public float seconds = 0f;
public float minutes = 0f;
public float moreSeconds = 0f;


void Start()
{
    score = 0;
    UpdateScore ();
    moreSeconds = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
}

void Update()
{
    seconds = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - moreSeconds; 
    if (seconds > 60) 
    {
        seconds = 0;
        moreSeconds = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        minutes = minutes + 1;
    }

    if (seconds < 10) 
    {
        timerText.text = "Time: " + (int)minutes + " : 0" + (int)seconds;
    } 
    else 
    {
        timerText.text = "Time: " + (int)minutes + " : " + (int)seconds;
    }
}

public void AddScore(int scoreInc)
{
    score += scoreInc;
    UpdateScore ();
}

void UpdateScore()
{
    scoreText.text = "" + score;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best option is to have 2 cameras one for in game actions and another for your result so when the mission ends you turn off the game camera and turn on the result camera

```
void whenLevelEnds(){
    GameObject gamecamObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("gamecam"); //give game cam and main cam tags so we would be able to find them
    GameObject menucamObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("menucam");
    Camera gamecam = gamecamObj.GetComponent<Camera>() as Camera;
       gamecam.enabled = false;
    Camera menucam = menucamObj.GetComponent<Camera>() as Camera;
       menucam .enabled = true;
}
```

you can set the game cam and menu cam to render different things on their **cullingmask** option for example set  the menu cam to only renders GUI objects

if you want to use **DontDestroyOnLoad** and want to get rid of showing player you can put your
player on a **Layer** and tell your camera to don't **render** that **layer** in cameras **culling mask**

you can put your **DontDestroyOnLoad** in **Awake** to protect your gameObject from being **destroyed** in a new scene

```
void Awake () {
    DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: That's a good light on how to solve the score problem, but I don't think answers his question about the DontDestroyOnLoad

Comment: i said the stuff because user asked for best option in the question i also edited the answer to fits better

Comment: Ah, I see. So the MenuCam will only display GUIText and stuff like that, and the GameCam will deactivate, so the level won't show up. I can use a button to reset the score and time and load the next level, then. That seems pretty straightforward. 

Thanks for the DontDestroyOnLoad information as well. I think I'll go ahead with the separate camera, but it's nice to have options.